# Inserting Data into DB ERROR: Columns of type 'VARCHAR' cannot hold values of type 'INTEGER'

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, derby

I have built a DB, and now I'm writing a function which inserts data into that DB.
I guess the problem is something I don't see, the error I get is:

> Columns of type 'VARCHAR' cannot hold values of type 'INTEGER'.

while I completely understand what that means I just can't get it to work.

here is my code for insertion:

```
public static void insertIntoCouponsDB(long COMPANY_ID, String TITLE, String START_DATE, String END_DATE, int AMOUNT, String TYPE, String MESSAGE, double PRICE, String IMAGE) throws SQLException {

    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);

    String sql = String.format("insert into Coupons (COMPANY_ID, TITLE, START_DATE,END_DATE,AMOUNT,TYPE,MESSAGE,PRICE,IMAGE) values (%d, '%s', '%s','%s',%d,'%s','%s',%.2f,'%s')",COMPANY_ID,TITLE,START_DATE,END_DATE,AMOUNT,TYPE,MESSAGE,PRICE,IMAGE);

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql, PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();

    resultSet.next();

    int id = resultSet.getInt(1);

    System.out.println("Insertion into Coupons DONE !!! New ID: " + id);

}

}
```

and this is the code for the tabke creation:

```
public static void buildCouponsDB() {

    try {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();



        String sql = "create table Coupons (" +
                "ID bigint not null primary key " + 
                "generated always as identity(start with 1, increment by 1), "+
                "COMPANY_ID bigint not null, "+
                "TITLE varchar(50) not null, "+
                "START_DATE date not null, "+
                "END_DATE date not null, "+
                "AMOUNT integer not null, "+
                "TYPE varchar(50) not null, "+
                "MESSAGE varchar(250) not null, "+
                "PRICE double not null, "+
                "IMAGE varchar(100) not null)";


        statement.executeUpdate(sql);
        System.out.println("Coupons Table has been Created Succesfully !!");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

}
```

can anybody help?
I am a begginer so sorry if its to easy of a question, but still, asking for help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You are using PreparedStatement with wrong way? why you are not using place holder instead of `%d, %s`...

Comment: isn't %d is the place holder for a whole number? (long, int...)

Comment: take a look at this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Your code is a victim or SQL Injection and Syntax error like you have now!

Comment: What database are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Derby DB.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like DerbyDB does not support implicit conversion from integers to varchar datatype, like many (most?) other databases do.
A quick review of [the documentation](https://db.apache.org/derby/manuals/index.html#docs_10.14) did not give any information about the implicit conversions.

There is [CAST](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.14/ref/rrefsqlj33562.html) function `CAST ( [ expression | NULL | ? ] AS dataType )`, but from the table in the documentation it appears that the conversion from all numeric datatypes (SMALLINT, INTEGER, BIGINT, DECIMAL etc) is not supported.
Luckily thete is another [CHAR(https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.14/ref/rrefbuiltchar.html) function, and it seems that this function can be used to convert numeric values to varchar datatye:

> **Integer to character syntax**
>
> CHAR ( integerExpression )
>
> **integerExpression**
>
> An expression that returns a value that is an
>   integer data type (either SMALLINT, INTEGER, or BIGINT). The result is
>   the character string representation of the argument in the form of an
>   SQL integer constant. The result consists of n characters that are the
>   significant digits that represent the value of the argument with a
>   preceding minus sign if the argument is negative. The result is left
>   justified.
>
> - If the first argument is a SMALLINT: The length of the result is 6. If
>     the number of characters in the result is less than 6, then the result
>     is padded on the right with blanks to length 6.
> - If the first argument
>     is an INTEGER: The length of the result is 11. If the number of
>     characters in the result is less than 11, then the result is padded on
>     the right with blanks to length 11.
> - If the first argument is a BIGINT:
>     The length of the result is 20. If the number of characters in the
>     result is less than 20, then the result is padded on the right with
>     blanks to length 20.

---

**So you must use CHAR fuction to convert numerics to VARCHAR datatype**.

A quick test I've done using `ij` derby client showed that the above is true:

```
ij> connect 'jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/myDB;create=true'
> ;
ij> create table x( x integer, y varchar(20) );
0 wierszy wstawionych/zaktualizowanych/usuniŕtych

ij> insert into x values( 1,1);
BúąD 42821: Kolumny typu 'VARCHAR' nie mog╣ przechowywaŠ wartoťci typu 'INTEGER'.

ij> insert into x values( 1, cast(1 as varchar));
BúąD 42X01: B│╣d sk│adniowy: Encountered ")" at line 1, column 43.
Issue the 'help' command for general information on IJ command syntax.
Any unrecognized commands are treated as potential SQL commands and executed directly.
Consult your DBMS server reference documentation for details of the SQL syntax supported by your server.

ij> insert into x values( 1, char(1));
1 wiersz wstawiony/zaktualizowany/usuniŕty
ij> commit;
ij> select * from x;
X          |Y
--------------------------------
1          |1

1 wiersz wybrany
ij>
```

---

**EDIT**

---

It seems that `CAST( 1 AS CHAR )` also works, I've done a test:

```
ij> insert into x values( 1, cast(1 as char));
1 wiersz wstawiony/zaktualizowany/usuniŕty
ij>
```

Comment: Here's the documentation page you were probably looking for: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.14/ref/rrefsqlj58560.html